# Не работает bootstrap -tab

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Добрый день.

Подключаю к проекту bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js и jquery.js + ещё скрипты (bootstrap.tab.js bootstrap.dropdown.js), но вкладки и выпадающие меню так и остаются статичными. Я не пойму, в чём дело, делаю, как в примерах.  Хочу, чтоб при нажатии на другой вкладке она становилась активной и появлялось содержимое для данной вкладки. Ну и точно такое же - с выпадающими меню.

Походу, у меня что-то со скриптами, т.к. отрисовка нормальная - в css всё нормально, а вот реакции на действия нет. Причём скачивал сборки с разных сайтов, и при генерации бутстрапа выбирал все компоненты.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать в данной ситуации.
Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.
В идеале покажите код или пример страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, как здесь http://bootstrap-3.ru/components.php#nav-tabs
В общем, проблема была сперва в отсутствии файла http://bootstrap-ru.com/204/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js , а потом он просто "корявый" был. Надо добвить ещё эти скрипты, хотя о них писали, но я, по-видимому, левый скачал, а сейчас просто тупо взял код их сайта и думаю, у них же работает, и передрал этот файл. В общем, всё хорошо. Спасибо. Вот пример, вдруг кому интересно http://plnkr.co/edit/tqf4hWTAtDNCWPH7Fi2y?p=preview